# How can i pass a URL explicitly in Scala

Tags: scala, web-crawler

Hello i am  new to Scala . I tried this code

```
def web ( url : Any) {
     | val ur= new URL("url")
     | val content=fromInputStream(ur.openStream).getLines.mkString("\n")
     | print(content)
     | }
```

when i pass a url like web("http://contentexplore.com/iphone-6-amazing-looks/")
it is showing error

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: url
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:585)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:482)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:431)
    at .web(<console>:22)
    at .<init>(<console>:23)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:11)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:704)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request$$anonfun$14.apply(IMain.scala:920)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.Line$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(Line.scala:43)
    at scala.tools.nsc.io.package$$anon$2.run(package.scala:25)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

My question is how can i pass a url explicitly in scala .Kindly suggest me an idea .Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you expect to which location `new URL("url")` points to?

Comment: Hello sschaef i am passing a url sorry i did not get your question i am totally new to scala kindly suggest an idea regarding when i pass a url i should get all the data related to that site . Kindly suggest an idea so that i can improve myknowledge . Thank you

Comment: Remove the quotes around url in the new URL line. And make the url parameter to the function a String rather than Any.

Comment: Not quite what you asked, but if I can make a plug, you might like to make your http calls using my Bee Client API (http://www.bigbeeconsultants.co.uk/bee-client) which will take care of things like closing the input stream cleanly etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this line is the problem:

```
val ur= new URL("url")
```

If you want to create a `URL` from the input param `url`, the code should be:

```
val ur= new URL(url)
```

With the error, the java `URL` class was trying to parse a `String` with value `"url"`, looking first for a recognized protocol (`http`, `https`, etc...) and not finding one, so that's why you were seeing that error.